# How to make text blink conditionally using java script

Tags: javascript

On a web page I have some text that I wish to blink under certain conditions (when counter is even) and not to otherwise

The problem is that once it starts blinking, it blinks all of the time. How can I stop it?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test blink</title>
</head>

<div id="wait-text">&nbsp</div>
<button onclick="updateText()">Click</button>

<script>
    var counter = 0;
    var wait_text = document.getElementById('wait-text');

    function updateText() {
        counter ++;
        wait_text.innerHTML = `wait ${counter}`;
        wait_text.className = '';
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            wait_text.innerHTML = `blink ${counter}`;
            wait_text.className = 'blinking';
        }
    }

    function blinker() {
        let fadeout = 1500;
        let fadein = 750;
        $('.blinking').fadeOut(fadeout);
        $('.blinking').fadeIn(fadein);
    }
    setInterval(blinker, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: The issue is because jQuery's fadeOut/ fadeIn apply an opacity value to the actual element and will continue to do so after the className is removed. Modern CSS using keyframes (in an answer below too) is both more performant and doesn't have state related problems like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I have created a class `blink` which contains CSS for blinking effect.
- then I am checking whether `counter` is odd or even.
- if it's even then I am adding `blink` class and if it's not than I am checking whether it's contains `blink` class or not. If it does then I am removing `blink` class otherwise do nothing.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#wait-text");
let counter = 0;
const updateText = () => {
  counter++;
  text.innerHTML = counter;
  if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    text.classList.add("blink");
  } else {
    if (text.classList.contains("blink")) {
      text.classList.remove("blink");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinkIt 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkIt {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wait-text">&nbsp</div>
<button onclick="updateText()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the interval id and call `clearInterval` on each button click, only starting the interval again when the counter is even. Furthermore, to stop all current and queued animations on the element, call `$('.blinking').stop(true, true)`.

```js
var counter = 0;
var wait_text = document.getElementById('wait-text');
let intvlId;

function updateText() {
    counter++;
    clearInterval(intvlId);
    $('.blinking').stop(true, true).show();
    wait_text.innerHTML = `wait ${counter}`;
    wait_text.className = '';
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        wait_text.innerHTML = `blink ${counter}`;
        wait_text.className = 'blinking';
        intvlId = setInterval(blinker, 500);
    }
}

function blinker() {
    let fadeout = 1500;
    let fadein = 750;
    $('.blinking').fadeOut(fadeout);
    $('.blinking').fadeIn(fadein);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wait-text">&nbsp;</div>
<button onclick="updateText()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .classList.toggle()

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test blink</title>
</head>

<div id="wait-text">&nbsp</div>
<button onclick="updateText()">Click</button>

<script>
    var counter = 0;
    var wait_text = document.getElementById('wait-text');

    function updateText() {
        counter ++;
        wait_text.innerHTML = `wait ${counter}`;
        wait_text.className = '';
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            wait_text.innerHTML = `blink ${counter}`;
            wait_text.classList.toggle("blinking"); //chang here
        }
    }

    function blinker() {
        let fadeout = 1500;
        let fadein = 750;
        $('.blinking').fadeOut(fadeout);
        $('.blinking').fadeIn(fadein);
    }
    setInterval(blinker, 500);
</script>
```